# Controlar la inserción de una página nueva desde HTML al dar Ctrl+p en el navegador

Tags: html

Estoy construyendo tablas en HTML de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna manera de indicar desde HTML que un `<table>` solo ocupe una página y cuando este acabe inserte una página nueva, algo similar a esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://pagedjs.org/

Comment: Ummmm amigo desde HTML desconozco pero con CSS puedes usar `background-repeat:;` anímate a usarlo !!